# What does a negative dwLowDateTime mean in the FILETIME structure?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, datetime

I know that `FILETIME` structure formed datetime value in 100 nanosecond step from 1st of Jan 1601. But what does mean `dwLowDateTime`'s value that less then 0???

Comment: It cannot happen, since `dwLowDateTime` is of type `DWORD`, which is an `unsigned` type. Anyhow, as specified by the documentation, the correct way to operate on a `FILETIME` is to copy its members in a `ULARGE_INTEGER` and then operate with its 64-bit field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means you are viewing it as an int rather than an unsigned int and hence it can show negative.

As Matteo Italia says you are better off placing it in a ULARGE_INTEGER as follows:

```
ULARGE_INTEGER uli;
uli.LowPart  = ft.dwLowDateTime;
uli.HighPart = ft.dwHighDateTime;
__int64 filetime64 = uli.QuadPart;
```

You can even do it with a memcpy as follows:

```
__int64 fileTime64;
memcpy( &fileTime64, &ft, sizeof( __int64 ) );
```